# What to do when the package (qpcR) downloads in R but cannot use a function in the package?

Tags: r

I am trying to run an old script and I successfully downloaded the qpcR package. However, it will not let me use the HQIC command. I have tried uninstalling qpcR and reinstalling it. I keep getting the following error down below. What can I do?

```
Loading required package: MASS
Warning: package ‘MASS’ was built under R version 4.0.5
Loading required package: minpack.lm
Loading required package: rgl
Loading required package: robustbase
Warning: package ‘robustbase’ was built under R version 4.0.5
Loading required package: Matrix
```

Comment: None of these are errors - they are warnings that you don't have the latest version of R installed. This doesn't have anything to do with being unable to use the HQIC command. That function simply doesn't exist in the package (according to the reference manual) It was removed in 2014

Comment: The package "ICglm" _does_ have the HQIC function. Perhaps you can try that.